# Should Orbital Bombardment be Considered a War Crime?

Tags: spaceships, politics, law-enforcement, space-warfare

One of the most common tactic in realistic interstellar war is the tried and true orbital bombardment.  The victor is often the one who holds the high ground, so it make sense to take the ultimate high ground and rain fiery death on you enemies.  But their is one thing that most people seem to leave out.  The damage that can be done to a planet by such acts.  Take this scene from the Expanse Season 5 (Obligatory Spoiler Warning https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=aGy04ZgeYvw)

And that was a single impact, from a planed out bombardment.  The asteroid that wiped out the dinosaurs was only five miles wide and still hit with the force of 10 billion atomic bombs and wiped out half of all life on earth.  Back to the Expanse example, the bombardment left 15 billion dead or wounded between the impacts, tsunamis, fires, earthquakes, dust in the atmosphere and all of the other apocalyptic side effects of such an attack.  So I really don’t see how bombing a planet with enough force to make a nuclear strike look like dropping a grenade until what ever government is left capitulated, could possibly be seen as anything less than an act of terrorism.  And I certainly can’t see any captain or admiral who engages in it even once being seen as anything less that a war criminal.

So, the billion credit question: **Would a sustained Orbital Bombardment be Considered a War Crime?**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119406/discussion-on-question-by-jacob-badger-should-orbital-bombardment-be-considered).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't really answerable, in that the person writing the universe gets to decide what the laws, mores, and situation is.  For example, in the game *Starcraft*, human worlds became infected with spores of an alien ecosystem capable of spaceflight called the Zerg, and another alien race exterminated all life on those worlds from orbit in an attempt to contain the infestation.  Is it a war crime if your obvious intent is to save human (and alien) lives overall?  Yet if one accepts that, how far is it to say the same about a planet infested with Nazis, or people of the opposing political party?

Each person in your world may have his own philosophy and principles, and may have a different opinion, and as you explore the balance and disagreements of those opinions you may begin to strengthen and justify your own.